# If $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is a Lebesgue density point for both measurable subsets $A$ and $B$, then it's also a density point for $A\cap B$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, lebesgue-measure

I came up with the following statement about the Lebesgue density point of two measurable sets in $\mathbb{R}$ when solving an exercise in Stein's real analysis.

> $L_A := \{x:x \text{ is a point of Lebesgue density of } A\}$, and let $L_B$ be defined similarly. Then $L_A \cap L_B = L_{A\cap B}$.

My attempt to prove the statement:

The inclusion $ L_{A\cap B} \subseteq L_A \cap L_B$ is clear, by considering the following inequality
$$
1= \lim_{r\to 0} \frac{|(x-r,x+r) \cap (A\cap B)|}{2r}  \leq  \lim_{r\to 0} \frac{|(x-r,x+r) \cap A|}{2r}  \leq 1
$$
We now prove the opposite inclusion. We assume $0$ is both a Lebesgue density point of $A$ and $B$ for simplicity. Our goal is to show that
$$
 \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{ (-r , r) \cap (A\cap B) }{2r } = 1.
$$
Denote $A_r =  A\cap (-r, r)$ and denote $B_r = B\cap (-r,r)$. Since we know that $ |A_r \cup B_r |  = |A_r| +|B_r| - |A_r \cap B_r|$ by inclusion-exclusion principle, $A_r \cup B_r = (A \cup B)\cap (-r,r) \subseteq (-r,r)$, and $A_r \cap B_r = (A\cap B )\cap (-r,r)$, we have
$$
  2r \geq |A_r \cup B_r| =  |A_r|+|B_r| - |(A\cap B)\cap(-r,r)|\implies 1\geq \frac{|(A\cap B)\cap(-r,r)|}{2r} \geq \frac{|A_r|}{2r}+\frac{|B_r|}{2r} - 1.
$$
By taking the limit $r \to 0$ and use the assumption that $0 \in L_A \cap L_B$, the RHS of the last inequality approaches $1$, and we're done.

I can't find any related statements in both Stein or other real analysis textbooks I own. This makes me to doubt about my proof. However, if the above statement is true, then we actually can use it to solve for example exercise 3 of chapter 3 in Stein.

> Suppose $0$ is a point of density of measurable $E$. Show that there exists a sequence $x_n \in E$ with $x_n \neq 0$, $(x_n) \to 0$, that satisfies
> (a) $-x_n \in E$ for all $n$
> (b) In addition, $2x_n \in E$ for all $n$.

Since this exercise can be formulated using inclusion-exclusion principle, the statement claimed above then easily solves it.

I'd like to ask whether the proof is correct. If it's false, can anyone provide a counterexample or point out the false argument that I've made. Thanks.

Comment: See Theorem 3.3.1 on p. 26 of [**The Density Topology on the Reals with Analogues on Other Spaces**](https://scholarworks.boisestate.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2166&context=td) by Stuart Nygard (2016; Masters thesis).